# Wufoo Form Editing

Tags: html, forms, wufoo

I'm wanting to find out how I change my form title from an `h2` tag to an `h1` tag from the Wufoo forms builder. I've been looking everywhere on their documentation and can not find out an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the markup of a form HOSTED by Wufoo. But if you download the HTML/CSS (avaialble in the code manager, the same place you get the embed code), you are free to change that tag. Or, you can use [Custom CSS](http://www.wufoo.com/2011/05/20/form-anatomy-custom-css/) to make that h2 look any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure you can do that... many of those "pre-made" type sites won't allow much customization. You might want to try to make your own form with the [HTML `<form>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp).

Answer (score 0):

you can download the embedded code provided for developer, you will get a .zip file, edit index.html file, edit form according to your needs, but do not change actual, name, type, method, action, value fields, add CSS classes you want and finally you are are ready to in your site, it work fine. I am using it on 30+ websites.